# Joining multiple columns into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using MSSQL 2008 and having troubles returning the rows the way I need it. The following query returns the following data.

Query:

```
SELECT [DATE_PULL] as d, [OWNER] as label, sum(VM_COUNT) as value 
FROM [VCENTER_INFO_HIST] 
GROUP BY OWNER, DATE_PULL

+-------------------------------------------------+
|    D       |   label        |  value            |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 06/30/2014 |    Test1       |       443         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 06/30/2014 |    Test2       |       456         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 06/30/2014 |    Test3       |       487         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 07/07/2014 |    Test1       |       1024        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 07/07/2014 |    Test2       |       2056        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 07/07/2014 |    Test3       |       2076        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|    D       |                value                 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 06/30/2014 | Test1: 443, Test2: 456, Test3: 487   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 07/07/2014 | Test1: 1024, Test2: 2056, Test3: 2076|
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'm thinking `PIVOT` is where you want to go with this.

Comment: This looks like a `group_concat()` thing (in MySQL should be easy)... but I don't know if there's an equivalent in SQL Server

Comment: Seriously, though.  This is a great link to a pivot example.  Instead of just pasting the answer here, you're going to learn alot more and have knowledge retention if we just show you the way and help you as you progress. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx

Comment: Just a note, where possible it's often cleaner to do this kind of operation at the display level rather than the db level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` abilities in SQL Server like so:

```sql
select distinct [DATE_PULL] as D, 
    stuff((select ', ' + [OWNER] + ': ' + convert(varchar(20), sum(VM_COUNT)) + '' as [text()]
                from [VCENTER_INFO_HIST] c where c.[DATE_PULL] = v.[DATE_PULL]
                group by c.[OWNER] 
                for xml path('')), 1, 1, '') as value
    from [VCENTER_INFO_HIST] v
```

Keep in mind, as the data set grows, this might be a bit inefficient since we are doing a sub query, but it's the only way I know how to do something like you stated above.  If there's another way, someone kindly point me in the right direction as well....

Anyway, you can find more information about [`STUFF` here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) and the [`FOR XML` here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx).  Although, if you want them to be independent columns, the answer Kris provided in the comments with the use of `PIVOT` is more likely what you would want.